# autocorrect -- articles

Tags: articles

*Some phones and computers also allow users to add their own words to the dictionary that **autocorrect** will use to avoid suggestions that are completely unrelated to what was intended.*

Here there isn't an article before *autocorrect* -- why? Also, is the notion of formality relevant here? Like this usage is informal and for an informal phrase we would write *the autocorrect* because there's usually one. Or *the autocorrect feature*

I noticed that when speaking of MS word, we write *AutoCorrect* which seems to work as a proper noun and has no article. E.g. "How do I turn on AutoCorrect in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that Microsoft capitalises *AutoCorrect* because it is the proper name for their spelling correction software. Apple seems to use *Auto-Correction*. However, it is quite common for specific brand names (particularly first to market) to be used by the public as generic terms for other similar brands. In the UK, two examples of this are *hoover* as a generic term for vacuum cleaners, and *tannoy* as a generic term for public address systems; in the US, many people refer to any brand of tissue as a 'kleenex'. Likewise, it seems that 'autocorrect' is used as a generic term for the spelling correction software on any device. When used as such, it is a *mass noun* (like 'software') so it does not need an article.

Comment: Furthermore, that embedded-capital thing seems to be mainly American. I have noticed that Americans think that the train company that runs between London and Paris, Brussels and Amsterdam is called 'EuroStar'. It's called Eurostar.